# Python what does the dollar sign mean in this example?

Tags: python, module, discord, sign

I was reading the Discord.py module's documentation and I stumbled upon the dollar sign, I would like to understand what does it stand for?

```
 if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Comment: It does literally nothing special, it just checks if a string startswith the actual string of `$hello`, startswith is a built-in python function

Answer (score 2):

It's common to see bot commands in Discord start with a prefix such as "$", "!", etc.  This is to differentiate bot commands from regular chat.

In terms of Python, '$hello' is just a regular string.